# Test-NG: turning a @BeforeClass into something else (@BeforeSuite maybe?)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

For a project of mine, I need two properties to be set at the JVM level before running tests (with testng, as the subject says). Here is the code I use to enforce the presence of these two properties:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class AbstractPamTest
{
    protected String user;
    protected String passwd;
    protected String badPasswd;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp()
    {
        user = System.getProperty("test.login");
        passwd = System.getProperty("test.passwd");
        if (user == null || passwd == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Please define test.login and"
                + " test.passwd before running tests");
        badPasswd = passwd + "x";
    }
}
```

This code has the problem that all my tests must inherit this class, therefore `setUp()` is run each time. How can I make this method run only once?

Comment: None of those variables are static. This will cause unexpected behavior in your tests. Indeed, if your setup is quite simple then you should use @Before to prevent any possibility of one unit test interfering with another unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your tests extend this class, you could just put this into a static initializer. This will only be executed once (when the class is loaded).

```
public class AbstractPamTest
{
  protected static final String user;
  protected static final String passwd;
  protected static final String badPasswd;

  static
  {
      user = System.getProperty("test.login");
      passwd = System.getProperty("test.passwd");
      if (user == null || passwd == null)
          throw new IllegalStateException("Please define test.login and"
              + " test.passwd before running tests");
      badPasswd = passwd + "x";
  }
}
```

Or put it in a completely different class, that is used/called by classes that need the password/user. You won't need to extend the AbstractPamTest then. Additionally you should provide getters/setter there, so that you can change user/password at runtime, if one testcase needs different values.

```
  private  static String user;
  private  static String passwd;
  private  static String badPasswd;

  static
  {
      user = System.getProperty("test.login");
      passwd = System.getProperty("test.passwd");
      if (user == null || passwd == null)
          throw new IllegalStateException("Please define test.login and"
              + " test.passwd before running tests");
      badPasswd = passwd + "x";
  }

  public static String getUser()
  {
    return user;
  }

  public static void setUser(String pUser)
  {
    user = pUser;
  }

  public static String getPasswd()
  {
    return passwd;
  }

  public static void setPasswd(String pPasswd)
  {
    passwd = pPasswd;
  }
```

Comment: good point... I'll do that. But I'd like to ultimately get rid of the inheritance, if at all possible.

Comment: @fge see the second part of answer, I'd suggest making a seperate class that keeps/handles/sets those values.

Comment: OK, I'll do that... But I thought TestNG had a builtin mechanism for that already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `@BeforeSuite`?

.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment then an answer.

Comment: It's neither, it's a question.